# HTML-JS age verification with appropriate messages

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I can't get it to display a message saying the data is valid.

Only the negative message is displayed.

I don't want the form to be sent, I need it to just display a message saying "positive message"

I need to meet these requirements:

> A) Date of birth field: which should receive valid days, months and years, as well as sending the focus to the next field, when they are correct.
>
> B) Marital status field: If the choice of marital status was Single, the date of birth must be analyzed and only validated if the person is over 15 years old.

I hope the positive message appears when the age is greater than 15, or when the selected marital status is different from "Single".

I expect a negative message to be sent when "single" is selected AND the age is less than 15.

I hope that by changing marital status or age, the negative message disappears and the positive message appears.

My effort so far:

```js
function idade() {
  let estadocivil = document.getElementById('iestadocivil').value;
  let inascimento = document.getElementById('inascimento').value;
  let conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo');

  let sucesso = document.getElementById('isucesso');
  let falha = document.getElementById('ifalha');

  if (estadocivil === 'solteiro') {
    let data = new Date();
    let ano = data.getFullYear();

    let anoNascimento = ano - parseInt(inascimento.substring(0, 4));

    if (anoNascimento <= 15) {
      conteudo.innerHTML = 'Solteiro needs age 15!';
      falha.innerHTML = 'negative message!';
      return false;

    } else {

      conteudo.innerHTML = '';
      sucesso.innerHTML = 'positive message';
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="inascimento">Ano de nascimento:</label>
<input type="date" name="nascimento" id="inascimento" required>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet, please add the code needed to execute your function and add to the description actual and expected outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add some HTML and gave the form an ID

You need a submit event handler.

You need to clear the messages or use one element for both succes and failure

```js
function idade() {
  let estadocivil = document.getElementById('iestadocivil').value;
  let inascimento = document.getElementById('inascimento').value;
  let conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo');

  let sucesso = document.getElementById('isucesso');
  let falha = document.getElementById('ifalha');

  if (estadocivil === 'solteiro') {
    let data = new Date();
    let ano = data.getFullYear();

    let anoNascimento = ano - parseInt(inascimento.substring(0, 4));

    if (anoNascimento <= 15) {
      conteudo.innerHTML = 'Solteiro needs age 15!';
      falha.innerHTML = 'negative message!';
      sucesso.innerHTML = '';      
      return false;
    } else {
      conteudo.innerHTML = '';
      falha.innerHTML = '';
      sucesso.innerHTML = 'positive message';
      return false;
    }
  }
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    const ageCheck = idade()
    if (!ageCheck) e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission. You can remove the test to always stop submission
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="iestadocivil" required>
    <option value="">Estado Civil</option>
    <option value="solteiro">Solteiro</option>
    <option value="casado">Casado</option>
    <option value="divorciado">Divorciado</option>
  </select>

  <label for="inascimento">Ano de nascimento:</label>
  <input type="date" name="nascimento" id="inascimento" required>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<span id="isucesso"></span>
<span id="ifalha"></span>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
```